# Encryption Function returning Set Length

Tags: javascript, hash

I am attempting to write a hash function (writing in JavaScript for easier testing) though I have a bit of an issue.

Larger, more popular cryptographic hash functions such as md5, sha1, etc. have a fixed length. How is this done exactly? For example, `"0"` and `"0123456789"` hashed are the same length.

This is my function at the moment:

```
String.prototype.encrypt = function() {
    var l = this.length,
        a = [],
        s = this.split('');

    s.forEach(function(v) {
        a.push(v.charCodeAt() << l);
    });

    s.forEach(function(v,i) {
        s[i] = (v.charCodeAt() << a[i]) << l;
    });

    return s.join('');
};
```

What can I do to have this return a string of a set length?

P.S: I know this isn't secure, I'm still working on that.

Comment: If you don't want to decrypt the string later, you probably mean [*hashing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) instead of *encryption*.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Does it really matter for the question?

Comment: Yes of course. A trivial hashing algorithm would start with a character array (single block) and change its values depending on the current character based on some rule. A (symmetric block-) encryption algorithm should not use the same block to do some rounds on, otherwise it would try to pack more data in than can be recovered which makes it undecryptable. Although, an encryption algorithm can be converted into a hashing algorithm with a little effort.

Comment: I've corrected your terminology.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Thanks. I was a bit uninformed when I made this question :)